# How to get email account from webview facebook login in my android application

Tags: android, android-facebook

I would like to implement that the user like my facebook fan page from android application .
Now I use javascript SDK to like fb fan page . For the first time ,javascript automatically show login page that the user must login to fb to like page . I want to keep email address when the user enter their email because next time not to show webview to the user if already have once login and when user click like fan page on webview I want to close webview and shwo another process. How can I implement it.

This is my tesing code.

```
public void btnCalculate(View v) {
    LoadWebView();
}

public void LoadWebView() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.web);
    dialog.setTitle("LikeOrWait");

    webView = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/bb.htm");
    WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebClientClass();
    webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
    WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);

    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
            "Application Name", "Loading...");

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            if (progressBar != null && progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                dialog.show();
            }

            view.clearHistory();
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
}
```

Where do I implement facebook like event to show another activity and how to get email address when the user login on webview